# Send a file to an alternative folder from an ftp folder using tcl and curl

Tags: curl, tcl

Hi guys I'm trying to send files from a ftp folder to a tempory folder on my debian machine but I receive a curl error "curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory". Here is the code snippet that is causing the error..

```
if {[catch {exec curl -o "/tmp/add/file/$name" -k -O ftp://user:passwd@ip:port/$section/$file/$name} error]} { putlog "error: $error"; }
```

Hope you can help both locations are on the same machine it's just about moving the files..

Comment: Can you upload it to a different location?

Comment: no get same error

Comment: On the same server? Does a different ftp client work? (It might be the error is accurate and your user just doesn't have permission, not a problem with how you're trying)

Comment: Tried 2 or 3 different clients and yes it's on the same server